# Saving dynamically created objects in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, save

In my WPF application I have a form presented to the user, the user fills out forms which is about, e.g. A location. These form entries are then used to construct a object from a custom class and on the next view details about the location entered are displayed.

What I need is a method to be able to save the dynamically created object so that when the application is closed and reopened i can display the name property of previously entered objects so that the user can reopen the data from previously entered objects.

Thinking I can serialize them into an .osl file, but that only saves the public values.
So I'm thinking there must be a much simpler way

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read about `.Net Serialization`.

```
 [Serializable]
    class Person
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable]
    class Address
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
    }



static public void SerializeToXML(Person p, Address add)
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\data.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, p);
                formatter.Serialize(stream, add);
            }
        }
        static void DeserializeFromXML()
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\data.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
            {

                Person p = (Person)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                Address add = (Address)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
```

Use:

```
Person p = new Person { Age = 23, Name = "Ram" };
            Address add = new Address { City = "Khurja,India" };
            SerializeToXML(p, add);
            DeserializeFromXML();
```

This way you can serialize/deserialize anything you want.

Comment: Great answer and I have got it working perfectly. Although do you know if it is possible using this method to save more than one object to the file and be able to deserialize them back into separate objects? As the current method just simply overwrites the xml file each time. and I know I can use StreamWriter to simply add to the xml file, but as I said deserializing back into separate objects becomes a problem then.